# Github Insights does not show specific user commits

Tags: git, github

> Github project -> Insights

We use Github **Insights** to understand the **contribution** of developers code in a project, so they could take ownership.

One user, no matter which projects repo he is part of, his **comments** and lines of code do not update.

Does not matter if he is the one to push or approve PR's.

**What is configured incorrectly for this to happen? How can this be fixed?**

Comment: Do his commits in the repository appear associated with his username like other people's or do they appear associated only with his personal (human) name?

Comment: Yes you are right, his personal name appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub associates contributions with an account based on the account's email address. If a user uses an email address not associated with their account, GitHub has no way to associate it with any account, and will simply display the user's personal name as specified in the commit or tag.

In order to associate this user's work with his commits, he'll need to add whatever email address he's using to his GitHub account.

Comment: Thanks! Where should he add his email too? He is logged in to his Github account locally...

Comment: Found it: git config --global user.email "email@gmail.com"